# A jwt.io verified JWT failed in C# by using UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Tags: oauth, jwt

I have the following JWT token

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0IiwiYXVkIjoiRDFDOTBCRUUtOEM1NC00RDZCLThENDYtOTU5NkJGQjRGMjhCIiwic3ViIjoiMTAwMCJ9.GdVBv2LPqKi1NmwPnnaGq6jz5WMLNkQOG9WttoH6Nfw=
```

and the secret is

```
BE7B9DD1-6197-4684-A232-5D680812ADC3
```

We get the following if we base64encode the secret

```
QkU3QjlERDEtNjE5Ny00Njg0LUEyMzItNUQ2ODA4MTJBREMz
```

It verifies with signature in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io)

The header is decoded to

```
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "HS256"
}
```

and the payload

```
{
   "iss": "http://localhost",
   "aud": "D1C90BEE-8C54-4D6B-8D46-9596BFB4F28B",
   "sub": "1000"
}
```

It's all good.  I've learned from the following articles

https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/webapi-owin and

http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

so the code I have in my Startup.ConfigureOAuth() is just a copy from theirs (Can't remember which one I saw first):

```
var issuer = "http://localhost";
var audience = "D1C90BEE-8C54-4D6B-8D46-9596BFB4F28B";
var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("BE7B9DD1-6197-4684-A232-5D680812ADC3");

// Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
        {
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
        },
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = context =>
            {
                context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
       }
   });
```

I tired with both Provider and without Provider.  But all I got is 401 and the following

```
{
    "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

I know my JWT is correct since jwt.io can decode it just fine.  Can someone please spot my error or if I should do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

You have copied code from examples that pull base64url encoded secrets from the configuration. Yet in your case the secret is in plain text. So just use:

```
var secret = "BE7B9DD1-6197-4684-A232-5D680812ADC3";
```

jwt.io shows that the secret used to sign the JWT you provided was actually the base64encoded variant `QkU3QjlERDEtNjE5Ny00Njg0LUEyMzItNUQ2ODA4MTJBREMz` that should have been base64decoded first.

Comment: Tried that too, I just didn't mention about it, but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the resulting JWT as well?

Comment: Z: I did put the JWT in my post.  I put everything that you can fill in at jwt.io

Comment: see edited answer: the plain text secret nowhere comes in to play; the JWT was signed using `QkU3QjlERDEtNjE5Ny00Njg0LUEyMzItNUQ2ODA4MTJBREMz` as if it were a "plaintext" key; so the other side must use that literal value to verify it